VBC Error '& e_emb.Message Visual Studio 22 Preview
I am trying to upgrade a vintage vb winform app to from framework 4.72 to .NET 8. I am using visual studio 2022 preview (latest version).  I have reduced the number of errors I get in the build process from over 9000 to 1.  This seems to be the most difficult one to solve.  In the error window I get this message:
Error (active)      " & e_emb.Message)  File:  vbc  Line 1
In my output window, amidst a sea of warnings the error appears as follows:

6>\lanserver\haim\DellDoc\Visual Studio \BARDApp12n\Reviewer.vb(3821,13): warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. ...
6>VBC : MessageBox.Show("The Message was not sent do to the following error : " & e_emb.Message)
6>\lanserver\haim\DellDoc\BARDApp12n\SRRemindDialog.vb(620,9): warning CA1416: ...
6>\lanserver\haim\DellDoc\BARDApp12n\Reviewer.vb(3814,21): warning CA1416: ...

While the output messages don't appear to be in any particular order, I do eliminate the error if I exclude the reviewer.vb (a winform) from the project.  My strategy now is to comment out portions of the code on that form until I find the culprit.  I couldn't find this specific problem on the web.  Does anyone have an idea where I can find the error?

Those are warnings, not errors. They are just telling you that you have code that will only work on Windows that, in theory, could be executed on other platforms. There may be some way to specify that your app is Windows-only that will prevent those error messages but you can just suppress them for that project.

It looks like there is a bug somewhere in the chain from the compiler message to the error window where it is not processed correctly.  The messages in the compiler output look reasonable.

Thank you @jmcihinney. Its always good to have another set of eyes look at the code. I didn't notice that the output referred to the line MessageBox.Show. The code in the error message box was somewhat cryptic.  The actual code is as follows:
MessageBox.Show("This reviewer has been sent a request." & vbCr & "Do you want to continue?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

I created the string outside the function call.  Strangely, I could also fix the error this way:
Dim ermsg = "This reviewer has been sent a request." & vbCr & "Do you want to continue?"
intresp = MessageBox.Show(ermsg, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

Using & or '+' to concatenate the strings didn't make a difference, but it would not accept either inside the call to MessageBox.Show().

Replacing the string concatenation operator & with + is not the right thing to do, and it could not fix your problem. It's not clear exactly what fixed it, but it wasn't this. Nor is there a problem with using & inside a function call.

I am describing the facts.  I agree the & and + probably didn't make a difference, but either operator in the function call created the error.  I had at least 10 such calls in the application.  Whenever the string was concatenated in the function call I got the error.  As soon as I eliminated the function call from the error, the program compiled.  Demoting this answer is a misrepresentation of the facts.

Just out of curiosity, replace vbCr with System.Environment.NewLine directly in the MessageBox.Show() like you had before.

The messageBox crashes as soon as I try to concatenate two strings.  Even this caused a crash  MessageBox.Show("Hello" & "World")    (Replacing the & with a + didn't make a difference).

.NET 8 is designed to be cross-platform, while .NET Framework is Windows-specific.
Since MessageBox.Show is a Windows Forms method, it's specific to Windows. To ensure compatibility, you might need to wrap it in a conditional compilation block if your application needs to support multiple platforms.
If you only intend to use this application on Windows, you can set Target OS to Windows in Project Properties for the project which will fix the warning.

Thank you #Jiachen for the suggestion.  In this case I definitely received an error as I explained in my answer and it prevented the program from compiling.  I will try to follow your suggestion to reduce the thousands of warnings I am receiving.

@JiachenLi  MessageBox.Show is not just a Windows Forms method.  It is also valid in WPF.
